# Render Content wrapped in ascx partial .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ascx

Is there anyway to wrap content with a partial view written in .ascx file. For example if I had a modal partial and I want the body content into the partial.

```
/Components/Modal.ascx

<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="modal-header>Static header <a>close</a></div>       
  <div class="modal-body">
     Yield Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Then on a more complex page would have something like this

```
<!-- Page Content -->
....
<% Html.Partial("Modal") %>
   Modal Body Content (Possible Another Partial)
<% /HTML Partial %>
```

I am not sure if this concept exists in MVC but basically borrowing the idea from client side frameworks like ember where you could specify a component with a `{{ yield }}` and any content that was wrapped inside the component tag gets placed there.

Comment: Never seen this in MVC so I think it doesn't exist. What you could do, is creating a seperate model for your modal. This model can be used as a property on other models. Then, you could create a partial view for your modal that you could use in several views with @Html.Partial("mymodal", Model.ModalModel)

Comment: How would you make the content in the modal dynamic. for example what if I had several partials to render inside of my modal content. then the modal partial loses any generic features.

Comment: Looks like custom Html Helpers using IDisposble might be the way to go will update when I get a working solution

Comment: Well ... if you call another partial in your modal, it will first search for the partial in the view folder with the same name as your controller.
Meaning: Call http://yourserver/Hello/Action will render a view containing your modal. If the modal calls another partial 'modalpartial' it will look for a view Views/Hello/modalpartial.cshtml. On the other hand, if you call http://yourserver/AnotherHello/Action which renders a view with the same modal, the partial Views/AnotherHello/modalpartial.cshtml will be rendered, both requiring a completely different model.